# Asymptotic expansion of an integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics, divergent-series, perturbation-theory

I came up with a simpler example which illustrates the technical difficulty I have encountered in my work.

Consider an integral depending on parameter $\epsilon$:

\begin{equation}
\int\limits^{\infty}_{1 + \frac{2 \epsilon^{2}}{R^{2} - \epsilon^{2}}}
\frac{1}{t^{2}-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^{2} - \epsilon^{2}\left(t+1\right)/\left(t-1\right)\,}}\,{\rm d}t.
\end{equation}

I am interested in the behaviour of this integral $\left(~\mbox{evaluated at}\ t = \infty~\right)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

This integral can be performed analytically, and it is straightforward to see that the end result diverges logarithmically as $\epsilon \to 0$. My question is: how to extract this logarithmic divergence without performing full integration ?. Naive expansion of the integrand in Taylor series in $\epsilon$ never leads to a logarithmic divergence.

In my real problem the integral cannot be evaluated analytically, but I am interested only in the logarithmic divergence. Is there a systematic way to extract it?

Thank you in advance!

Yegor

Comment: What's the lower limit of integration?

Comment: I don't think it is essential for the question I ask. I'm interested only in the divergence coming from the upper limit of integration. One can take the lower limit to be 2.

Comment: But the integral does converge when $\epsilon=0$, no?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you're integrating over $[2,\infty)$ then $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2 \frac{t+1}{t-1}}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-3\epsilon^2}},$$ so your integrand is $O(1/t^2)$ as $t \to \infty$.  The integral is thus bounded, and there is no logarithmic singularity as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: First, the integral is convergent for any fixed value of $\epsilon$. I want to view the end result as a function of $\epsilon$. The primitive function evaluated at $t = \infty$ equals to $-\frac{\log(-2R^2 + \epsilon^2 + 2R \sqrt{R^2 - \epsilon^2})}{2 R}$. If you now consider the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ you find that it diverges as $\log \epsilon$.

Comment: @Yegor, please reread my last comment.  I'm telling you that, for $\epsilon$ small enough,

$$
0 \leq \int_2^\infty  \frac{1}{t^2-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 - \epsilon^2 \frac{t+1}{t-1}}} dt \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-3\epsilon^2}} \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{t^2-1} dt = \frac{\coth^{-1}(2)}{\sqrt{R^2-3\epsilon^2}},
$$

so there is no singularity as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you Antonio! Yes, I agree with what you are saying. I was too sloppy in formulating the question (I tried to simplify it too much). It is true that viewed as an integral over $[2,\infty)$ this integral is non-singular in $\epsilon$. In reality the integration variable runs from $1 + \frac{2 \epsilon^2}{R^2 - \epsilon^2}$ to $\infty$. I have checked with Mathematica that this one has $\log(\epsilon)$ singularity. I have changed the question accordingly. Sorry about this confusion.

Answer (score 5):

First make the change of variables $x = \epsilon^2\frac{t+1}{t-1}$ to get

$$
I(\epsilon) = \int_{\frac{R^2+\epsilon^2}{R^2-\epsilon^2}}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2 \frac{t+1}{t-1}}} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\epsilon^2}^{R^2} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R^2-x}}.
$$

Fix $0 < \delta < R^2$ and split the integral into the two pieces

$$
I(\epsilon) = I_1(\epsilon) + I_2 = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\epsilon^2}^{\delta} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R^2-x}} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\delta}^{R^2} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R^2-x}},
$$

each of which is finite for $\epsilon > 0$.  We see here that the singularity comes from $I_1(\epsilon)$, whose largest contribution comes from a neighborhood of $x = \epsilon^2 \approx 0$.  Informally,

$$
I_1(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\epsilon^2}^{\delta} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R^2-x}} \approx \frac{1}{2} \int_{\epsilon^2}^{\delta} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R^2}} \approx - \frac{\log(\epsilon^2)}{2\sqrt{R^2}}.
$$

To make this precise, let's write

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 - x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 - x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2}},
$$

so that

$$
I_1(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{R^2}} \int_{\epsilon^2}^{\delta} \frac{dx}{x} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\epsilon^2}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 - x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2}}\right)dx.
$$

The integrand in the integral on the right is bounded by a constant for all $x \in [0,\delta]$ (note that $\lim_{x\to 0}$ exists), and the integral on the left is

$$
\frac{\log(\delta/\epsilon^2)}{2\sqrt{R^2}} = -\frac{\log \epsilon}{|R|} + O(1).
$$

Putting all this together, we conclude that

> $$
> \int_{\frac{R^2+\epsilon^2}{R^2-\epsilon^2}}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2 \frac{t+1}{t-1}}} = -\frac{\log \epsilon}{|R|} + O(1)
> $$
>   as $\epsilon \to 0$.

In fact we know what the constant in the $O(1)$ term is; it's just the finite terms we threw out along the way.  Indeed,

$$
I(\epsilon) = -\frac{\log \epsilon}{|R|} + C + o(1),
$$

where

$$
C = \frac{\log \delta}{2|R|} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 - x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2}}\right)dx + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\delta}^{R^2} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{R^2-x}}.
$$

This constant depends on $R$ but not on $\delta$, so we may take the limit as $\delta \to R^2$ to obtain

$$
\begin{align}
C &= \frac{\log |R|}{|R|} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{R^2} \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 - x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2}}\right)dx \\
&= \frac{\log(2|R|)}{|R|}.
\end{align}
$$

Thus

> $$
> \int_{\frac{R^2+\epsilon^2}{R^2-\epsilon^2}}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)\sqrt{R^2-\epsilon^2 \frac{t+1}{t-1}}} = -\frac{\log \epsilon}{|R|} + \frac{\log(2|R|)}{|R|} + o(1)
> $$
>   as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Great, Antonio! Thank you very much! In general the idea is to localize the point from which the divergence comes, right?!

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}$
$\ds{%
{\cal J}
\equiv\!\!\!\!\!
\int\limits^{\infty}_{1 + \frac{2 \epsilon^{2}}{R^{2} - \epsilon^{2}}}\!\!\!\!\!
{\dd t \over \pars{t^{2}-1}\sqrt{R^{2} - \epsilon^{2}\left(t+1\right)/\left(t-1\right)\,}}
=
{1 \over \verts{R}}
\int\limits^{\infty}_{1 + \mu^{2} \over 1 - \mu^{2}}\!\!\!
{\dd t \over \pars{t^{2}-1}\sqrt{1 - \mu^{2}\left(t+1\right)/\left(t-1\right)\,}}
}$

where $\ds{\mu \equiv \epsilon/R}$.
\begin{align}
{\cal J}
&=
\int_{1 + \mu^{2} \over 1 - \mu^{2}}^{\infty}
{\dd t \over \root{t - 1}\pars{t + 1}\root{\pars{1 - \mu^{2}}t - 1 - \mu^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\int^{1 - \mu^{2} \over 1 + \mu^{2}}_{0}
{\dd t/t^{2}
 \over
 \root{1/t - 1}\pars{1/t + 1}\root{\pars{1 - \mu^{2}}/t - 1 - \mu^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=
\int^{1 - \mu^{2} \over 1 + \mu^{2}}_{0}
{\dd t
 \over
 \root{1 - t}\pars{t + 1}\root{\pars{1 - \mu^{2}} - \pars{1 + \mu^{2}}t}}
\\[3mm]&=
-\,{1 \over 2}\int^{1 - \mu^{2} \over 1 + \mu^{2}}_{0}{\dd t \over t - 1}
+
\overbrace{\int^{1 - \mu^{2} \over 1 + \mu^{2}}_{0}\bracks{%
{1
 \over
 \root{1 - t}\pars{t + 1}\root{\pars{1 - \mu^{2}} - \pars{1 + \mu^{2}}t}}
- {1 \over 2\pars{1 - t}}}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\equiv\ {\cal K}\pars{\mu}}}
\\[3mm]&=
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{1 - {1 - \mu^{2} \over 1 + \mu^{2}}} + {\cal K}\pars{\mu}
=
-\ln\pars{\verts{\epsilon \over R}}
+
{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{1 + \bracks{\epsilon \over R}^{2}}
+
{\cal K}\pars{\epsilon \over R}
\end{align}

---

$$\bbox[15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{
{\cal J} \sim -\ln\pars{\verts{\epsilon \over R}}
\quad\mbox{when}\quad \epsilon \gtrsim 0}}
$$

---

The 'next contribution' is finite and it's given by
$$
{\cal K}\pars{0} = {1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over t + 1}
=
{1 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}
$$